# how to delete spaces in specific elements of a vector?

Tags: r

I have this vector:

```
x <- c("a", " b", "c", "d", " e", "f")
```

There are spaces in `x[c(2,5)]`

How to delete the spaces to get all elements without spaces?, like this:

```
x <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `gsub`:

```
gsub(" ", "", x)
```

Note that this approach will remove any spaces in the elements of x, not only those at the beginning or end of each element.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
library(stringr)
str_trim(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `gsub`

```
gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$","",x)
```